# Тормозит плавный скролл js на телефоне

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Мне нужно сделать плавный скролл. `scroll-behavior: smooth;` и `window.scrollTo({ top: to, behavior: "smooth" });` - не подходит т.к. не поддерживается в Safari. Делал по такой схеме:

1. Получаю положение элемента (где он находиться относительно всей страницы по высоте)
2. Получаю `window.pageYOffset` - текущее положение вьюпорта.
3. Вычисляю дистанцию.
4. Через `window.scrollBy` скроллю вниз на `дистанция/скорость`
5. Повторяю выше указанные действия если расстояние до цели больше шага прокрутки через `setTimeout`.

На пк всё работает нормально, скроллиться с замедлением до элемента плавно. На телефоне же (реальном, не DevTools) - лагает. Почему так и что можно сделать?

*Использование библиотек крайне не желательно.*

Вот код:

```
class jscroll {
        
            static to(item)
            {
                const stepCoefficient = 100;
                const timer = 1;
        
                let to = document.querySelector(item).getBoundingClientRect().top;
                let distance = to - window.pageYOffset + stepCoefficient;
        
                let step = 10;
                let oldStep;
        
                function scroll() {
                    oldStep = step;
                    step = distance / stepCoefficient;
        
                    window.scrollBy(0, step);
        
                    distance = to - window.pageYOffset + stepCoefficient;
        
                    if (step > 1 && step != oldStep)
                        setTimeout(scroll, timer);
                    else
                        window.scrollTo(0, to);
                }
                scroll();
            }
        }
        
        export { jscroll }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверено на мобильном устройстве.

Думаю, причиной неплавной работы может служить слишком частый вызов функции (всего 1 миллисекунда задержки перед новым выполнением). Вызывать её следует примерно в 17 раз реже (для  обыкновенного экрана с частотой 60 Гц). С помощью [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) можно делать вызовы, которые "чаще всего совпадают с частотой обновления экрана" и не перегружать устройство.

В моём примере нумерация облегчает проверку плавности. Переменная `offset` ответственна за отступ, а `speed` - за скорость пролистывания.

```js
function scrollTo(item) {
    let offset = 0;
    let speed = 20;

    let to = document.querySelector(item).getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let dy = to - window.pageYOffset + offset;
    let moreZero = (dy >= 0)? 1 : -1;
    let dist = dy * moreZero;
    let step = speed * moreZero;
    window.requestAnimationFrame((scroll = function() {
        if ((dist -= speed) > 0) {
            window.scrollBy(0, step);
            window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
        }
    }));
}

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = () => {
    scrollTo("#l");
}


// ниже - создание элементов для проверки
function createDivs() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        let e = document.createElement("div");
        e.innerHTML = i;
        document.body.appendChild(e);
    }
    let e = document.createElement("div");
    e.id = "l";
    document.body.appendChild(e);
}
createDivs();
```

```html
<button>Scroll</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! Я немного подкорректировал ваш код под то что мне нужно и всё заработало везде и плавно! :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо

`window.scrollTo(0, to);`

выбрать какой-то самый верхний елемент (например хедер)

и скролить к нему так:

```
scrollTargetEl.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'start',
});
```

[scrollIntoView doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

у меня есть проект где такой способ работает везде.

И тогда вам не нужно будет писать костили `static to(item)`

Comment: Мне нужно от кнопки скролить в любому выбранному по id или классу элементу.
То что вы предложили выше в моём случае не подходит. Да, оно работает плавно везде и хорошо, но `behavior: 'smooth'` не поддерживается в браузере Safari.